# Does backbone.js really require underscore.js?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, javascript-framework

As i am new to **backbonejs** and **underscorejs**, I want to know core meaning of those.

As my understanding underscorejs is just like as **jQuery** library, we are using those functions in backbonejs.

We can't develop backbonejs applications without underscorejs.

Am i right? If my understanding is wrong please clear on this with simple words/examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right - Because backbone.js heavily depends on underscore.js. Like it says on the project page: *"Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js"* And yes, underscore.js is just as jQuery a collection of helper functions.

Comment: underscore is a templating language, you use it build an html code based on your backbone model.

Comment: @zaynetro not true, underscore is a utility library, one of its utilities is templating

Comment: @JamesHalsall thanks, still learning

Comment: Thanks for the answers and I understood no alternatives for underscorejs(for backbonejs). Got a doubt and cleared. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

Backbone relies heavily on the Underscore library. You *cannot* have a Backbone application without Underscore.

Answer (score 3):

From http://underscorejs.org/

> Underscore is a utility-belt library for JavaScript that provides a
>   lot of the functional programming support that you would expect in
>   Prototype.js (or Ruby), but without extending any of the built-in
>   JavaScript objects. It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux, and
>   Backbone.js's suspenders.

Answer (score 2):

Its is true in a sense that backbone doesn't work without a helper library like underscore.
But you can use [lodash](http://lodash.com) instead of underscore. 
I would prefer it over underscore since it has more features like high performance, AMD support, custom build support etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, underscore is a hard dependency in Backbone. But there is light at the end of the tunnel if you like Backbone but not JQuery or Underscore: check out Exoskeleton ([https://github.com/paulmillr/exoskeleton](http://exosjs.com)).

Exoskeleton will load JQuery and Underscore if it finds them but function fine without them.

Quotes from their website:

> - Exoskeleton is a faster and leaner Backbone for your HTML5 apps.
> - Both jQuery and Underscore are 100% optional in Exoskeleton. You can just throw them away.
> - Your views will be rendered up to 5.5 times faster* when Exoskeleton is used without jQuery. They will also consume 2 times less memory.
> - You can just replace Backbone with Exoskeleton and it will all work as before.
> - Exoskeleton passes 100% of Backbone and Chaplin test suites with or without dependencies.

Comment: This project no longer appears to be under active development. The website link is dead the the git repo hasn't been touched in years.

Comment: project is now found at https://github.com/paulmillr/exoskeleton - i'll modify answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to use underscore with backbone, you can use underscore with knockout, but if you want to use backbone; backbone's only hard dependency is `Underscore.js`.